# Create mysql user and group [windows]

Tags: java, mysql

I have mysql5.5.20 on my windows machine.
I am not able to execute following command:

```
groupadd mysql
useradd -G mysql mysql
```

I am doing this because I am configuring Nakamura(Sakai) for MySql and I found these commands at:
https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/display/KERNDOC/Configuring+Nakamura+for+MySQL

Thanks for help!

Comment: These commands are linux/unix commands they are not going to work on Windows ! the first creates a new group "mysql" and the second adds a user "mysql" and adds it to the group "mysql"

Answer (score 1):

Logon to MySQL console using following command:

```
mysql -u root -p<password>
```

Then execute following commands

```
Create User 'sakaiuser'@'localhost' identified by 'ironchef';
Grant All on nakamura.* to 'sakaiuser'@'localhost' identified by 'ironchef';
Flush Privileges;
```

Hope it will fit your needs!